# how to parse html file in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i dont know how to work on it guide me on this
    i have to fetch  html file which is im my resource folder example.html in application i don’t know how to parsh this all file in iphone some one help me how can i parse this static html file in iphone  please explane some one to me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Ryanair.com</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Ryanair/Standard.css" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Ryanair/datePicker.css" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt"><script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/skysales_3F5DBD0632207A3932CD626AEDC1A849.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/skysales_B5A6631CD62DEC33073F138AE4A7C8D2.js"></script><script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            google.load('ads.search', '2');
        </script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt">
      Date.dayNames=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thusday','Friday','Saturday'];
      Date.monthNames=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
      if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
        $.dpText={
          TEXT_PREV_YEAR:'Previous year',
          TEXT_PREV_MONTH:'Previous month',
          TEXT_NEXT_YEAR:'Next year',
          TEXT_NEXT_MONTH:'Next month',
          TEXT_CLOSE:'Close',
          TEXT_CHOOSE_DATE:' '
        };
      }

      var datePickerFormat='yyyy-mm-dd';
      var datePickerDelimiter='-';
      Date.format=datePickerFormat;
            var pln="en";
            var pcu="IE";
    </script></head><body><noscript xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt"><p class="error noprint">
      ERROR:
      This service makes use of Javascript, which appears to be turned off.
      Click <a href="activateJavascript.htm">here</a> to learn how to activate it.
    </p></noscript><form novalidate="true"method="post" action="FRSelect.aspx" id="SkySales" ><div><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value=""><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value=""><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUBMGRkg4UKvNNb1NbM14/2n9zUxhNQ++A="></div><div id="header" style="width: 100%;"><div id="blu"><a href="http://www.ryanair.com"><img src="Images/Ryanair/logoyelbg.gif" width="228" height="42" alt="Ryanair.com Homepage" title="Ryanair.com Homepage"></a></div><div id="yel" onclick="this.firstChild.innerHTML='WWW156 2011-09-29 06:31:09 reglixj3c555jw1v|413894465 ';"><span title="DNS: www156 62.73.129.156 10.37.2.156 "> </span>Search » <b>Select</b> » Services » Payment » Itinerary</div><input type="hidden" id="sysdate" value="2011-09-29"><input type="hidden" id="systime" value="06:31:09"></div><div><div id="body"><div id="wrapper"><div id="error"><input type="hidden" name="errorlist" value=""><script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var msg = "";          

        if (msg.length  > 0) {
          msg = msg.replace(/([\.|:])\s*([^\.]+)/g,"$1``$2") 
          var msg_array = msg.split("``");
          var newMsg = "";
          for (var idx = 1; idx < msg_array.length + 1; idx++){
            if (newMsg.indexOf(msg_array[msg_array.length - idx]) == -1)  { 
              newMsg = msg_array[msg_array.length - idx] + "\n" + newMsg ;
            }
          }
          alert(newMsg);
        }
      });
    </script></div><div id="main"><p><b>Here are the flights and fares available on the requested date(s).</b></p><ol><li>Select the flight of your choice.</li><li>Click on the fare name to see the fare rules.</li></ol><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {          
          var minDepArr = ('2011 09 29 12 31').split(' ');
      var minDep = new Date(minDepArr[0],minDepArr[1]-1,minDepArr[2],minDepArr[3],minDepArr[4]);


      $(".avlLst").each(function(){
       if($(this).find("input[type='radio']").size() == 0){
          $("input[id$='_ButtonSubmit']").attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
        }
      });


      $("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
      var re = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}");
      var m = re.exec($(this).val());
      if(m != null){
      var regexp = /([0-9]{2})(\/)([0-9]{2})(\/)([0-9]{4})(\s)([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/gi;
      var depArr = m[0].replace(regexp,'$5 $1 $3 $7 $8').split(' ');
      var dep = new Date(depArr[0],depArr[1]-1,depArr[2],depArr[3],depArr[4]);
      if(dep <= minDep){
              $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('checked','');
              }
          }
          });
        });

      function setTabIndex(marketIndex, index){
      var fld=['',
      ''];
      var i=marketIndex==1?0:1;
      document.getElementById(fld[i]).value = index;
      postBack();
      }

      function postBack(){
      ;
      }

      var pleaseWaitMessage = 'Please Wait...';
      var marketHeaders = ['','Going Out','Coming Back'];

      function feesTaxes(fltKeys,names){
      var mkts=[];
      for(var k in names){
      var market=names[k].charAt(names[k].length-1);
      mkts.push(market);
      $("div#taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody"+market).css('background-color','#A3AECC').find(".hdr").html('<span>'+pleaseWaitMessage+'</span>').css('background-color','#FFFF99')
      .ajaxError(function(evt,req,sett){
      $(this).html('<span>Unavailable... try again!</span>').css('background-color','#FFBBBB');
      });
      }
      $.get("FRTaxAndFeeInclusiveDisplay-resource.aspx",
      {'flightKeys':fltKeys.join('+++'), 'numberOfMarkets':fltKeys.length, 'keyDelimeter':'+++'},
      function(data,stat){
      $htm=$(data);
      for(var i=0,ml=mkts.length;i<ml;i++){
        if($($htm[i]).html().match(/RefreshWindow/) ) {                 
          window.location.reload(true);
        }       
      $("div#taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody"+mkts[i]).css('background-color','white').html('<p class="hdr">'+marketHeaders[mkts[i]]+'</p>'+$($htm[i]).html());
      }
      $('big#totalPrice').text($($htm[$htm.size()-1]).text());
      }
      );
      }      

      function selFlight(o){
      if(!o) return false;      
      $(o).parents('table:first').find("div[class^='planeImg']").css('background-position','top left');      
      $(o).parents('table:first').find("tr").removeAttr('class');
      var tro=$(o).parents('tr:first').attr('class','on');      
      var pval=[],pname=[],doJson=true;     

      var A=parseIDDate(tro.attr("id"));      
      var outDTarr=new Date(A[1],A[2],A[3],A[4]+1,A[5],A[6]);      

      $(".avlLst table").each(function(){        
        var $chkbs=$(this).find("input[type='radio'][name*='market']");       

      if(A[0]==1 && $chkbs.is("input[name*='market2']"))
      {          
          $chkbs.each(function(){
            var troB=$(this).parents('tr:first');
            var B=parseIDDate(troB.attr("id"));
            var inDTdep=new Date(B[1],B[2],B[3],B[4],B[5],B[6]);
            if(outDTarr>=inDTdep)
      {
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('checked','');
      $("div[class^='planeImg']", troB).css('background-position','top left').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }else
      {
      $(this).attr('disabled', '');
      $("div[class^='planeImg']", troB).attr('disabled', '');
      }
      });
      }

      var $chkb=$chkbs.filter(':checked');

      if($chkb.size()!=0)
      {
      pval.push($chkb.val());pname.push($chkb.attr('name'));
      $chkb.parent().prev().children('div').css('background-position','top right');      
      }
      else if($chkbs.is(':enabled'))
      {
      doJson=false;
      if(A[0]==1)
      {
      $chkbs.filter(':enabled:first').attr('checked','true').trigger('click');      
      }

      }
      else $("div[id*='taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody']", this.parent).find("*:not(.hdr)").remove();

      });

      if(doJson)
      {
            feesTaxes(pval,pname);
      }
      }

      function parseIDDate(s){
      var a=s.split('_');
      for(var k in a) a[k]=parseInt(a[k].replace(/^0([0-9]+)/,'$1'));
      return a;
      }

      var nbrMarkets=2;

      var dateRanges=[[],[new Date(2011,9,2), new Date(2011,9,2)],[new Date(2011,9,5), new Date(2011,9,5)]];
      var localization={
      inPast:'You cannot search earlier than the current date.',
      datesOverlap:'Your outbound date range cannot overlap your return date range',
      timesOverlap:'Please recheck the flights you selected\nYour second flight(s) must DEPART at least 1 hour(s) after your first flight(s) ARRIVES!',
      bookToday:'Unfortunatley due to security restrictions, If you wish to book a flight departing today.\nYou must either make the booking through your local RYANAIR CALL CENTER or at the AIRPORT.'
      };

      function checkDate(market,days){
      var flexi=Math.abs(days)==7?true:false;
      var idx=days>0?1:0;
      var today=new Date(), tomorrow=new Date(); tomorrow.addDays(1);
      if(idx==0 && dateRanges[market][idx] <= today){
      alert(localization['inPast']);
      return false;
      }
      if(nbrMarkets > 1){
      var overlap=false;
      if(market==2 && idx==0 && dateRanges[market][idx] <= dateRanges[market-1][idx]) overlap=true;
      else if(market==1 && idx==1 && dateRanges[market][idx] >= dateRanges[market+1][idx]) overlap=true;
      if(overlap){
      alert(localization['datesOverlap']);
      return false;
      }
      }
      return true;
      }     

      function checkTimes(){
      if(nbrMarkets < 2) return true;
      var DA=[0,0];
      $(".avlLst table input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){
      var A=parseIDDate($(this).parents("tr:first").attr("id"));
      DA[A[0]-1]=new Date(A[1],A[2],A[3],A[4],A[5],A[6]);
      });
      $("input[id*='oTime']").each(function(){
      var A=parseIDDate($(this).val());
      DA[A[0]-1]=new Date(A[1],A[2],A[3],A[4],A[5],A[6]);
      });
      if((DA[1]-DA[0]) <= (60*60*1000)){
      alert(localization['timesOverlap']);
      return false;
      }
      return true;
      }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      // This could probably be cleaned up
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonNextDay1']").click(function(){return checkDate(1,1);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonNextWeek1']").click(function(){return checkDate(1,7);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonPreviousDay1']").click(function(){return checkDate(1,-1);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonPreviousWeek1']").click(function(){return checkDate(1,-7);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonNextDay2']").click(function(){return checkDate(2,1);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonNextWeek2']").click(function(){return checkDate(2,7);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonPreviousDay2']").click(function(){return checkDate(2,-1);});
      $("a[id*='LinkButtonPreviousWeek2']").click(function(){return checkDate(2,-7);});

      $("a[id*='tab_']").click(function(){
      var A=this.id.split("_");
      var tabDate=new Date(A[2],A[3]-1,A[4]);
      var dtime=new Date(), today=new Date(dtime.getFullYear(),dtime.getMonth(),dtime.getDate());
      return true;
      });

      $("table[id*=ttable] th").click(function(){
        eval($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
       }).hover(function(){
        $(this).find("a").css("text-decoration", "underline");
        },function(){ $(this).find("a").css("text-decoration", "none");
      });

      $(".avlLst table").find("div[class^='planeImg'],input[type='radio']").click(function(){selFlight(this);});
      var firstRadio=null;
      $(".avlLst table").each(function(){
      var $chkbs= $("input[type='radio'][name*='market'][lwst='true']:enabled:first", this);
      if($chkbs.size() == 0){
        $chkbs = $("input[type='radio'][name*='market']:enabled:first", this);
      }
      $chkbs.each(function(){
      $(this).attr('checked','checked').parents('tr:first').attr('class','on');
      if(firstRadio==null) firstRadio=this;
      });
      var filter=function(){
      var flnum=this.value.replace(/.*FR~\s*(\d+)~.*/, 'FR$1');
      var a=preselectflights.split(',');
      for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) if(a[i].replace(/\s/g, '')==flnum) return true;
         return false;
      };

      if(preselectflights!=''){
          $("input[type='radio'][name*='market']:enabled", this).filter(filter).eq(0).each(function(){
      $(this).attr('checked','checked');
      firstRadio=this;
      });
      }
      });
      $(firstRadio).trigger('click');

      displayPopUpFareRule = getFareRule;
      displayPopUpFareRule('K','K2LOW|K|FR|BND2||en-IE','ADT');
      });
      var preselectflights='';

    function getFareRule(classOfService, fareRuleKeys, paxTypes){
      var url='FareRules.aspx?fareRuleKeys=' + fareRuleKeys +'&class=' + classOfService + '&paxTypes=' + paxTypes;
      $('div#fareRules').load(url + ' #main h2,#main div', function() {
        $('#main div.avlLst > table td:nth-child(3)').each(function(index, cell) { $(cell).wrapInner('<a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a>'); });
        $('#fareRules').jqm({overlay: 30, modal: false, onShow: showFareRules}).jqmAddTrigger('#main div.avlLst > table td:nth-child(3) *').jqmAddClose('#fareRules h2 span');
      });
    }

    function showFareRules(hs)
      {
        var pos = $(hs.t).offset();
        var width = $(hs.t).width();
        $('#fareRules').css( { 'left': (pos.left + width) + 'px', 'top': pos.top + 'px' });
        hs.w.show();
      }

    </script><div class="avlBlk"><h2>Going Out <span>From Aarhus - Malaga</span></h2><table><tr><td align="left" class="chgOff"><a id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_LinkButtonPreviousDay1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$LinkButtonPreviousDay1','')">« Previous Day</a></td><td align="right" class="chgOn"><a id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_LinkButtonNextDay1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$LinkButtonNextDay1','')">Next Day »</a></td></tr></table><div class="avlLst avlLst1"><p id="taxAndFeeInclusiveDivHeader1"><b>Select A Flight</b></p><div id="taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody1" class="drilldown"><p class="hdr">Select a Flight</p></div><table><tr id="1_2011_9_2_23_05_00"><td><div class="planeImg1" title="Click to select this fare on this flight"></div></td><td><input id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_RadioButtonMkt1Fare1" type="radio" name="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$market1" value="K~K2LOW~BND2~~RoundFrom|FR~2523~ ~~AAR~10/02/2011 19:30~AGP~10/02/2011 23:05" onclick="return raise('SelectFare', new SelectFareEventArgs(1, 1, 'K'))" required="true" requiredError="Please select a flight and fare in every market." checked lwst="true"></td><td>Regular Fare</td><td>Adult<br></td><td align="right" style="font-size:110%;">449.00 DKK<br></td><td></td><td><b>Sun</b>2 Oct 11<br><b>Flight</b>FR 2523</td><td>19:30 Depart<br>23:05 Arrive</td></tr></table><div style="clear:both; width: 100%; text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:infoWin('trvfee',0,0,'EN')">Fares do not include optional fees/charges. For a full list of Ryanair fees, please click here</a></div><div class="clr"></div></div></div><div class="avlBlk"><h2>Coming Back <span>From Malaga - Aarhus</span></h2><table><tr><td align="left" class="chgOff"><a id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_LinkButtonPreviousDay2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$LinkButtonPreviousDay2','')">« Previous Day</a></td><td align="right" class="chgOn"><a id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_LinkButtonNextDay2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$LinkButtonNextDay2','')">Next Day »</a></td></tr></table><div class="avlLst avlLst1"><p id="taxAndFeeInclusiveDivHeader2"><b>Select A Flight</b></p><div id="taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody2" class="drilldown"><p class="hdr">Select a Flight</p></div><table><tr id="2_2011_9_5_15_50_00"><td><div class="planeImg2" title="Click to select this fare on this flight"></div></td><td><input id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_RadioButtonMkt2Fare1" type="radio" name="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$market2" value="C~C2LOW~BND2~~RoundFrom|FR~2522~ ~~AGP~10/05/2011 15:50~AAR~10/05/2011 19:30" onclick="return raise('SelectFare', new SelectFareEventArgs(2, 1, 'C'))" required="true" requiredError="Please select a flight and fare in every market." checked lwst="true"></td><td>No Taxes</td><td>Adult<br></td><td align="right" style="font-size:110%;">379.00 DKK<br></td><td></td><td><b>Wed</b>5 Oct 11<br><b>Flight</b>FR 2522</td><td>15:50 Depart<br>19:30 Arrive</td></tr></table><div style="clear:both; width: 100%; text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:infoWin('trvfee',0,0,'EN')">Fares do not include optional fees/charges. For a full list of Ryanair fees, please click here</a></div><div class="clr"></div></div></div><div class="section right" style="width:38%;padding:4px;"><div class="bld" style="font-size:16px;margin-bottom: 4px;"><p style="float:left;"><big>Total</big></p><p class="rght"><big id="totalPrice">Please Wait...</big></p></div><p><small>Optional charges such as administration and checked baggage fees are not included.<br><a href="javascript:infoWin('trvfee',0,0,'EN');">Click here for details</a></small></p></div><div style="display: none; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; background-color: white; width: 33%; padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;" id="fareRules"></div><div class="btnRight"><input class="buttonRight" onClick="return validate(this) &amp;&amp; checkTimes() &amp;&amp; preventDoubleClick();" type="submit" name="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$ButtonSubmit" value="Select and Continue" id="AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_ButtonSubmit"><button id="NewSrch" class="button" onclick="&#xA;                  window.location='FRSearch.aspx';&#xA;                &#xA;          return false;&#xA;        ">New Search</button><style type="text/css">
      .ad_header {color:#191970;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px}

                 .ad_line1 {color:#0000FF;font-size:13px; text-decoration:underline}
                 .ad_url {color:#008000;margin-bottom:12px; text-decoration:none}

      .ad_text {color:#191970;text-decoration:none}
      .wide_ads {padding:5px;}
      div.ads ul {margin: 0px; list-style: none;}
         .narrow_ads {padding:2px;position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 780px; width:200px;}
    </style><div id="wide_ad_unit" class="ads wide_ads"></div><div id="narrow_ad_unit" class="ads narrow_ads"></div><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  

        var channels = {'DE':'1901616133','ES':'1730142402','FR':'4307283847','GB':'3975277388','IE':'0091594208','IT':'9330300293','NL':'6066899700','PL':'0911139945','SE':'1735271438','Other':'1974134150'};        
        var channelid= channels['IE'];           
        if (channelid == null) channelid='1974134150';     

    var pageOptions = {
        'pubId' : 'pub-3031568651010206',
        'query' : 'Malaga Flight',
        'channel' : channelid,
        'linkTarget' : '_blank',
        'siteLinks' : true,
        'sellerRatings' : true
        };

    var adblock = {
    'container' : 'narrow_ad_unit',
        'number' : 8,
    'width' : '250px',
        'lines' : 3,
    'fontFamily' : 'verdana',
    'colorText' : '#191970',
        'fontSizeTitle' : '13px',
    'fontSizeDescription' : '11px',
    'fontSizeDomainLink' : '11px',
    'colorBackground' : '#BFD6F7',
        'colorDomainLink' : 'blue',
        'colorBorder' : '#BFD6F7'
    };

        var adblock2 = {
        'container' : 'wide_ad_unit',
        'number' : 5,
        'width' : '400px',
        'lines' : 3,
        'fontFamily' : 'verdana',
        'colorText' : '#191970',
        'fontSizeTitle' : '13px',        
        'fontSizeDescription' : '11px',
        'fontSizeDomainLink' : '11px',
        'colorDomainLink' : 'blue',
        'colorBackground' : 'white',
        'colorBorder' : 'white' 
    };
        new google.ads.search.Ads(pageOptions, adblock);

    </script><div id="YahooBottomSelectAds"></div><script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        keywordsToUse = "Malaga Flight";
        resultsHeader = "Sponsored Listings";
        currentLanguage = "en";
        currentCulture = "IE";
        destination = "Malaga";

        YahooAds_SetFrame();
      });
    </script></div></div></div><div class="clr"></div><div id="footer"><div id="fLinks"><a href="http://www.ryanair.com" title="Home">Home</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/faqs.php" title="F.A.Q." target="_blank">F.A.Q.</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/conditions.php?view=privacy" title="Privacy Policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/conditions.php" title="General Terms &amp; Conditions of Carriage" target="_blank">General Terms &amp; Conditions of Carriage</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/copywrite" title="Terms of Use" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="http://www.ryanair.com/site/EN/faqs.php?sect=CONTACT&amp;div=int_sup" title="Contact Us" target="_blank">Contact Us</a> | <a href="javascript:infoWin('trvfee',0,0,'EN');" title="Fees">Fees</a></div><div id="copyr">Copyright 2009 Ryanair Ltd.</div><input type="hidden" id="language" value=""><input type="hidden" id="culture" value=""><script type="text/javascript"> xtnv=document; xtsd=(window.location.protocol.indexOf('https:')==0?'https://logs152':'http://logc158'); xtsite=(window.location.hostname.indexOf('www.bookryanair.com')!=-1)?'384235':'385193'; xtn2="3"; xtpage="BookingProcess_IE::Select"; xtdi="1"; xt_multc="&x1=2&x2=20111002&x3=20111005&x4=AAR&x5=AGP&x6=1&x7=3"; if(window.xtparam!=null) window.xtparam+=xt_multc; else window.xtparam=xt_multc; </script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ryanair/xtcore.js"></script><noscript><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="http://logc158.xiti.com/hit.xiti?s=384235&amp;s2=3&amp;p=BookingProcess_IE::Select&amp;di=1"></noscript></div></div></div><div class="clr"></div><script type="text/javascript"> 
//
var theForm = document.forms['SkySales'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.SkySales;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//
</script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
                    var events = new Array();

                    function register(eventName, functionName)
                    {
                        if (eval(events[eventName]) == null)
                        {
                            events[eventName] = new Array();
                        }
                        events[eventName][events[eventName].length] = functionName;
                    }

                    function raise(eventName, eventArgs)
                    {
                        var undefined;

                        if (events[eventName] != undefined)
                        {
                            for (var ix=0; ix<events[eventName].length; ix++)
                            {
                                if ( eval(events[eventName][ix] + "(eventArgs)") == false)
                                {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                // --></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
                    function SelectFareEventArgs(marketIndex, fltIndex, classOfService)
                    {
                        this.paxFares   = marketPaxFares['mkt'+marketIndex+'|flt'+fltIndex+'|'+classOfService];
                        this.marketIndex = marketIndex;
                    }
                // --></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
                function AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_Validate(eventArgs)
                {

                    var dots;
                    var sel;
                    var numOfMkts = 2;
                    var msg = new Array (
                "", "", 

                    0 );

                    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfMkts; i++)
                    {
                        sel  = '';
                        dots = document['SkySales']["AvailabilityInputFRSelectView$market" + i];

                        if (dots == null) 
                        {
                            alert("");
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if (dots[0]) // array
                        {
                            for (var j = 0; j < dots.length; j++)
                            {
                                if (dots[j].checked)
                                {
                                    sel = dots[j].value;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else // single
                        {
                            if (dots.checked)
                            {
                                sel = dots.value;
                            }
                        }

                        if (sel == '')
                        {
                            alert(msg[i-1]);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }


                function displayPopUpFareRule(classOfService, fareRuleKeys, paxTypes)
                {
                    var url = '/skysales/FareRules.aspx?fareRuleKeys=' + fareRuleKeys +'&class=' + classOfService + '&paxTypes=' + paxTypes;

                    if (!window.fareRuleWindow || fareRuleWindow.closed)    // has not yet been defined
                    {
                        fareRuleWindow = window.open(url,'fareRule','width=250,height=251,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fareRuleWindow.open(url,'fareRule','width=250,height=251,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0');
                        fareRuleWindow.focus();
                    }
                }

                // --></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
                                    function paxFare(paxTypeDesc,classDesc,fareRuleKey)
                                    {
                                        this.paxTypeDesc = paxTypeDesc;
                                        this.classDesc = classDesc;
                                        this.fareRuleKey = fareRuleKey;
                                    }
                                    var marketPaxFares = new Array();

                    marketPaxFares['mkt1|flt1|K'] = new Array();

                            marketPaxFares['mkt1|flt1|K'][0] = new paxFare('Adult','Regular Fare','K2LOW|K|FR|BND2||en-IE');

                    marketPaxFares['mkt2|flt1|C'] = new Array();

                            marketPaxFares['mkt2|flt1|C'][0] = new paxFare('Adult','No Taxes','C2LOW|C|FR|BND2||en-IE');

                // --></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- 
                                    function AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_initialize()
                                    {

                                    } // end of Availability_initialize

                // --></script><script type="text/javascript"> 
//
var RegisterFunctionsWithEvents =  new Array(register('Validate', 'AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_Validate'), register('WindowLoad', 'AvailabilityInputFRSelectView_initialize'));
//
</script></form><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:usr="urn:the-xml-files:xslt">
          //defined in common.js
          $(document).ready(function(){
                WindowInitialize();
          });
    </script></body></html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

This code will parse through your HTML or destination, load into a string, and then with componentsSeparatedByString below will actually find artifacts in your HTML code, and return whatever is between those two segments. You can build off of this!

```
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.url.com/test.htm"];

NSString *escapedUrl = [request   
                        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrl];

NSError *error;
NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

NSString *question = [[[[HTML componentsSeparatedByString:@"html tags to find"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"end of html to find"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: i have to take some extra file for use this just like THpple.h or it not vital to take please guide me how to work on

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Nolan Waite's HTMLReader](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader) project to parse a very complicated HTML5 response easily and reliably.

It's easy to setup and use, I highly recommend it.

Here's the example from the README:

```
#import <HTMLReader/HTMLReader.h>

// Parse a string and find an element.
NSString *markup = @"<p><b>Ahoy there sailor!</b></p>";
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:markup];
NSLog(@"%@", [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"b"].textContent);
// => Ahoy there sailor!

// Wrap one element in another.
HTMLElement *b = [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"b"];
NSMutableOrderedSet *children = [b.parentNode mutableChildren];
HTMLElement *wrapper = [[HTMLElement alloc] initWithTagName:@"div"
                                                 attributes:@{@"class": @"special"}];
[children insertObject:wrapper atIndex:[children indexOfObject:b]];
b.parentNode = wrapper;
NSLog(@"%@", [document.rootElement serializedFragment]);
// => <html><head></head><body><p><div class="special"> \
<b>Ahoy there sailor!</b></div></p></body></html>

// Load a web page.
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      NSString *contentType = nil;
      if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
          NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
          contentType = headers[@"Content-Type"];
      }
      HTMLDocument *home = [HTMLDocument documentWithData:data
                                        contentTypeHeader:contentType];
      HTMLElement *div = [home firstNodeMatchingSelector:@".repository-description"];
      NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
      NSLog(@"%@", [div.textContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace]);
      // => A WHATWG-compliant HTML parser in Objective-C.
  }] resume];
```